# pip can't find distribution of PyGTK after python update

Tags: python, pip, pygtk

I've installed python 2.7.10 from tar.xz, which was downloaded from official site. Then I've linked /usr/local/bin/python2.7 with /usr/bin/python2.7 and /usr/bin/python. Also I've reinstall pip `sudo apt-get install python-pip --reinstall`.

Now, when I try to install PyGTK via pip `sudo pip install PyGTK`, I get:

```
The directory '/home/s-quark/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/s-quark/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting PyGTK
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyGTK (from versions: )
  Some externally hosted files were ignored as access to them may be unreliable (use --allow-external PyGTK to allow).
No matching distribution found for PyGTK
```

Comment: `Then I've linked /usr/local/bin/python2.7 with /usr/bin/python2.7 and /usr/bin/python`
Needs clarification.

Comment: @Himanshu Mishra, I did:
`sudo ln /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
 sudo ln /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python2.7`

Comment: The problem you are facing is that it cannot find a python distro. What happens when you do `$ python` in the console?

Comment: @Himanshu Mishra, interpreter starts: `Python 2.7.10 (default, Jun 21 2015, 00:20:54) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> `

Comment: Have you considered using virtual environments? That usually fixes any dependency issues.

Comment: @Gx1sptDTDa, thanks, I'm already use anaconda =) So far, so good)